# Does Arquillian Cube works with RestEasy

Tags: docker, jersey, resteasy, jboss-arquillian, docker-java

Arquillian Cube isn't working with RestEasy Implementations.

I am getting error some things like below:

Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/vnd.docker.raw-stream and type class java.io.InputStream

Comment: Well I don't see any problem why it should not work, I will need more information. But for what I see is that you have in classpath two JAXRS implementations, the RestEasy and the one that comes with Docker-Java

Comment: Yes I am having RestEasy as my JAXRS Implementation, but in Docker-Java they used Jersey as JAXRS Implementation. So I am getting above mentioned error. I think internally there is a conflict on Jaxrs Implementation.

Comment: Please check this link: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/261522

Comment: Yeah, sadly we cannot do a lot about this. What I suggest is doing next thing. Create a "Maven/Gradle" module which will contain the functional tests, then at that point you don't need to define RestEasy just arquillian cube. Then everything would work.

Comment: For example, In First Module all RestEasy Stuff and In Second Module Arquillian Cube Stuff's right?

Comment: Exactly. Also it can be considered a good practice.